# How can I mark a contentDocument or ContentDocumentLink?

Tags: files, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I made a lightning web component to set if a content document it is approve or reject but I cant create any field in this objects... There is a way to mark if a Content document was approve or reject or its still pending??

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create new fields in the Content Version object which represent a specific version of a document in Salesforce. It's available through the Object manager.

Links:

[Add fields to Content version](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_fields.htm)

[Content version documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can create fields on **Content Version** which would be visible on the documents/uploads.. (This is in lightning experience)

Also, we can use [getRecordUi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_record_ui) to retrieve all the related details on the lightning web component